# syntax question for object initialization

Tags: go, syntax

I have the following working code

```
    serverFile, _ := os.OpenFile("server.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    debugFile, _ := os.OpenFile("debug.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)

    Logger = &BufferedLogger{
        ServerWriter:    serverFile,
        DebugWriter:     debugFile,
        BufferSize:      100,
    }
```

which I like to simplify, if possible. I tried

```
    Logger = &BufferedLogger{
        ServerWriter, _:    os.OpenFile("server.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644),
        DebugWriter, _:     os.OpenFile("debug.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644),
        BufferSize:      100,
    }
```

That is wrong syntax. Can someone give me a hint to fix it, or is that impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do it all in one statement. And there's a reason for that: *you should be handling the error, not ignoring it*. Any function that might cause an error will have a multi-valued return, so that you can't use it as an argument to another function, or in an initializer — only in a multi-valued assignment, where you can capture and check the error.